# Ask Same Android Studio Permissions Over And Over

Tags: java, android-studio

I need to access the user's location, and the permission for it is crucial for my app.
I tried this code but it did not ask for permission the second time (and so forward):

```
while(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
{
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, permissions, 1);
}
```

Comment: forget about making it work.. If a user encounters same dialog box again and again , he will most probably uninstall the app..  Human tendency

Answer (score 1):

If the permission is really crucial to continue in the app, as far as I know, the only think you can do is just to finish the app when you get in the permissions callback that this permission has not been granted.

This way the next time the app is opened it will ask again for the location permission.

We check for permissions at the main activity and show a toast that says that the permissions are required and finish the main activity in one app which makes no sense using it without location. And the app is published in the google play store.

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (permissions.length > 0 && requestCode == REQUEST_PERMISSIONS) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            setUp();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.permissions_required, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Even though it might be better if the rest of the app could be used without location, but sometimes there is no other way and if you try to ask for the same permission once and again the dialog will not show up at some point.